# Over use of Oracle With clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, common-table-expression

I'm writing many reporting queries for my current employer utilizing Oracle's `WITH` clause to allow myself to create simple steps, each of which is a data-oriented transformation, that build upon each other to perform a complex task.

It was brought to my attention today that overuse of the `WITH` clause could have negative side effects on the Oracle server's resources.

Can anyone explain why over use of the Oracle `WITH` clause may cause a server to crash? Or point me to some articles where I can research appropriate use cases? I started using the `WITH` clause heavily to add structure to my code and make it easier to understand. I hope with some informative responses here I can continue to use it efficiently.

If an example query would be helpful I'll try to post one later today.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to pose this question at http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Airy fairy statements like "overuse of the with clause could have negative side effects" are useless and must be challenged with requests for hard data. *How much* is "overuse"? *What* negative side effects, exactly? "We had a query with a WITH clause and it slowed everything down" is not a valid objection to the clause in general. On the other hand, "*Inappropriate* use of the with clause could have negative side effects" is a statement I might agree with.

Comment: To be more specific the individual who told me this was a OCP certified SQL developer with a masters in computer science. He works at a large hospital in southern California. He said that their main reporting server had crashed from the overuse of with clause by report developers eating up server resources. Which spawned this question...

Comment: I've used `with` to simplify a big reporting query into steps with good results. I do check the query plans generated to make sure the DB isn't doing anything stupid. But I do that on all my big queries, with or without `with`. I occasionally have to use a global temp table to keep the steps separated, due to either bad stats I can't update, or queries that combine local tables & linked server queries.

Comment: _Can anyone explain why over use of the oracle with clause may cause a server to crash?_ I'd suggest asking, "Why" of the source of this claim, _an OCP certified SQL developer with a masters in computer science_.

Comment: The conversation took place in an interview and haven't seen then applicant since. If I do I'll ask him and post his reply, but since this is a knowledgeable community I wanted to pose the question for reference if that chance does arise. Brilliant idea though... Brilliant.

Comment: For those who are reading this but need some more explications about how such temporary tables could look like, I put together an example how to use the WITH clause to create such a temporary static table:

http://www.giombetti.com/2014/02/14/using-sql-with-clause-to-create-temporary-static-tables-at-query-time/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_with_clause.htm it looks like this is a way to avoid using temporary tables.  However, as others will note, this may actually mean heavier, more expensive queries that will put an additional drain on the database server.

It may not 'crash'.  That's a bit dramatic.  More likely it will just be slower, use more memory, etc.  How that affects your company will depend on the amount of data, amount of processors, amount of processing (either using `with` or not)

Comment: While using `with` instead of temp tables may have more expensive queries, the temp tables have to be populated by queries. So the temp table version will have more queries, even though smaller queries. Storing into and retrieving from temp tables add load in addition to the queries to fill them. If all the work has to be done, I don't see how using temp tables will reduce load. (In general, I've seen bad query plans where temp tables in the middle drastically reduced the work and load on DB. . . .

Comment: Also, if you have a result that can be re-used in more than one query, a temp table (or materialized view?) could reduce over all load. Of course the temp table is values at a point in time, so will not stay consistent with its sources as they change.